# .NET framework compatibility: 3.5 SP1 & 4.0 Client Profile

Tags: .net, frameworks

My addin requires .NET 3.5 SP1, client has .NET 4 client profile, 
Is it enough? I am trying to find a picture or diagram which shows relations among versions of .NET framework.  thanks

The other way to say, is .NET 4 client profile a superset of .NET framework 35 SP1(not .NET framework 35 client profile)? thanks

Answer (score 2):

If your addin requires .NET 3.5 SP1 Client Profile, .NET 4.0 Client Profile is enough (it literally superseeds 3.5 SP1 in a sense). Read [Version Compatibility in the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602939.aspx) for more info. Also see [List of .NET Framework versions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_.NET_Framework_versions) to see which comes after which.

Comment: No, My addin requires .NET 35 SP1 not .NET 35 SP1 client profile. It seems after I install .NET 4.0,  Ribbon shows up. However, another question pops up, I specify .NET 35 SP1 in prerequisite list of setup project. When installer runs, why it does not install .NET 35 SP1 automatically? Installer does not say the PC need install .NET framework at all.  Does that mean if .NET 4 client profile exists, previous .NET framework can;t be installed or no need to install?

Comment: so if a PC has .NET 4 client profile, it can run an addin that requires .NET 35?

Comment: looks like not true. My addin requires .NET 35, end user has .NET 4 client profile,  it does not work (UI not show up)

Comment: As I already pointed out.  The reason its not working is because .NET 4 Client Profile is not the full framework.  Your installer should verify that either .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 or .NET Framework 4 is installed.

Answer (score 2):

Any .Net 3.5 application can run on Version 4.0. Be aware of the client profile missing many libraries, so if your addin requires the full .Net 3.5 runtime, it probably won't work on the client profile alone.

Comment: thanks. Yes, that's what I observed. one end user has .NET 4 client profile, and my addin does not work. In fact, partially works, UDFs works fine, but no Ribbon shows up at all.

Comment: Your client will have to install the full .NET Framework in that case.  NET 4 client profile is a subset of .NET Framework 4 not .NET Framework 3.5 SP1

Comment: I specify .NET framework 35 SP1 as prerequisite in installer, it seems if there is .NET 4 client profile, installer does not ask to install .NET framework 3.5 SP1. Is this a bug in windows installer? not matter is or not, how do I make installer (VS setup project) to install .NET 35 SP1? I specify it in prerequisite list, but it does not install .net 35 sp1 when installer finds .NET 4 client profile.